# binding parameters and PDO

Tags: php, pdo

If the parameters for statement 1 and 2 are identical, do I need to re-bind, or can I do this?

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ... thing = :thing ...");
$stmt->bindParam(':thing',$thing);
$stmt->execute();
// do something with data
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT something else ... thing = :thing ...");
$stmt->execute();
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually mean:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ... thing = :thing ...");
// ...
```

**No**, you are assigning `$stmt` to a new `PDOStatement` object, which does not hold the information that was stored in the old object.

Comment: yep yep, forgot to write `prepare`. Have edited to fix. Thanks, wasn't sure what carried over in terms of objects.